# How parce a XML DataTable xmlns=“http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data” to a DataTable in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, soap, datacontract

I am consuming a Web service from my app in `c #` and it returns the following structure:

```xml
<DataTable xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Data">
    <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:msprop="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msprop">
        <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="Table" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:element name="Table">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="FUENTE" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="TIPO_DOC" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="NUIP" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="NOM1" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="NOM2" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="APE1" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="APE2" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="DEPTO_EXP" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="MUN_EXP" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="F_EXP" msprop:OraDbType="106" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="ESTADO_CEDULA" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="NUM_RESOL" msprop:OraDbType="107" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="ANO_RESOL" msprop:OraDbType="107" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="DOCUMENTO_CANCELADO" msprop:OraDbType="107" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="OBSERVACION" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="GENERO" msprop:OraDbType="126" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="FECHANACIMIENTO" msprop:OraDbType="106" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
                                <xs:element name="F_CONSULTA" msprop:OraDbType="106" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
                            </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:choice>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
    <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
        <NewDataSet xmlns="">
            <Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
                <FUENTE>RNEC</FUENTE>
                <TIPO_DOC>CC</TIPO_DOC>
                <NUIP>54778455</NUIP>
                <NOM1>ANGEL</NOM1>
                <NOM2>MIREIDA</NOM2>
                <APE1>RAMOS</APE1>
                <APE2>VALLEJOS</APE2>
                <DEPTO_EXP>PERU</DEPTO_EXP>
                <MUN_EXP>RICAURTE</MUN_EXP>
                <F_EXP>1998-07-22T00:00:00-05:00</F_EXP>
                <ESTADO_CEDULA>VIGENTE</ESTADO_CEDULA>
                <NUM_RESOL>0</NUM_RESOL>
                <ANO_RESOL>0</ANO_RESOL>
                <DOCUMENTO_CANCELADO>0</DOCUMENTO_CANCELADO>
                <GENERO>FEMENINO</GENERO>
                <FECHANACIMIENTO>1978-04-14T00:00:00-05:00</FECHANACIMIENTO>
                <F_CONSULTA>2019-08-29T11:21:03-05:00</F_CONSULTA>
            </Table>
        </NewDataSet>
    </diffgr:diffgram>
</DataTable>
```

And I need to pass that answer to a `class` or a`DataTable` as such in `C #`, since since I can have the data in variables I could work it, but I don't know how to convert that `XML` to a valid data type in my program

I have this class to be able to enter the data, if it helps:

```cs
 class DataResultClass
    {
        string FUENTE { get; set; }
        string TIPO_DOC { get; set; }
        string NUIP { get; set; }
        string NOM1 { get; set; }
        string NOM2 { get; set; }
        string APE1 { get; set; }
        string APE2 { get; set; }
        string DEPTO_EXP { get; set; }
        string MUN_EXP { get; set; }
        string F_EXP { get; set; }
        string ESTADO_CEDULA { get; set; }
        string NUM_RESOL { get; set; }
        string ANO_RESOL { get; set; }
        string DOCUMENTO_CANCELADO { get; set; }
        string GENERO { get; set; }
        string FECHANACIMIENTO { get; set; }
        string F_CONSULTA { get; set; }
    }
```

To consume the service I use the following:

```cs
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("urlservice.svc") as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = "GET";
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string resp = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding

```cs
XmlTextReader xmlreader = new XmlTextReader(new System.IO.StringReader(resp));
DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(DataTable));
DataTable datos = (DataTable)ser.ReadObject(xmlreader);
```

So in the end, I will keep my code like this:

```cs
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("urlservice.svc") as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = "GET";
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string resp = reader.ReadToEnd();
XmlTextReader xmlreader = new XmlTextReader(new System.IO.StringReader(resp));
DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(DataTable));
DataTable data= (DataTable)ser.ReadObject(xmlreader);
```